# Connect existing Git repository to existing Github fork after the fact

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I am very new at Git and Github, and I think I didn't do things correctly. Here's what I've done chronologically so far:

1) I wanted to work on an open source project that existed on Github. I didn't know much about Git at the time, so I just downloaded a copy of the source code (not using Git) to a folder on my laptop.

2) I made some changes to the source code (using Visual Studio). I added the project to source control in Visual Studio, which by default uses Git, so it created a local Git repository.

3) I went to the original master project on the Github website and created my own fork of it. So now, my personal fork on Github is a copy of the original source code, without my changes.

Now, I want to push my local code changes to the Github fork, but I'm not sure how to get everything in sync.

I'm pretty sure that what I SHOULD have done (before making my code changes) would have been to make a local clone of my Github fork, and opened THAT repository in Visual Studio to make my code changes, but that's not what I did. I fear that if I now make a local clone of my Github fork, I'll either overwrite my code changes, or I'll have two separate local repositories that aren't connected.

Is there some way to make my current local Git repository (that was created by Visual Studio) "be" the local clone of my Github fork after the fact?

I have the Visual Studio Github plugin, but haven't done anything with it yet, other than log in. The other options that I have are "Clone" and "Fork". I'm not sure that I should do either of those things. I don't want to "Clone" because I already have the source code (and have made changes to it). I don't want to "Fork", because I have already forked the master project to my own fork on the Github website.

I'd like to set up Visual Studio so that my existing project/repository is connected to my Github fork, so that when I commit code changes in Visual Studio, they get committed to my Github fork.

What is the best way to fix all of this?

Comment: Clone the fork. Copy your changes into the clone. Check with `git diff` that all changes you introduced are there. Now, commit and you are done. By this, you will merge all your local commits into one.

Comment: To preserve all the commits you made you could try to extract your changes as git patches.

Comment: @MichaelHoff, thanks. I didn't have multiple commits that I needed to keep, so I followed your first suggestion, and it worked great.

Comment: I modified the answer to contain this simpler solution also. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you did the following:

1. Download contents of repository to local folder.
2. Initialize new git repository in local folder.
3. Commit everything as initial commit.
4. Do some changes and commit them.

This situation can be easily resolved. You have to extract your commits as patch-files which you then apply on the cloned fork. That way you can directly transfer commits between separated git repositories.

```
# create the copy
wget https://github.com/mhoff/pelican-global-rst-include/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip && rm master.zip && mv pelican-global-rst-include-master rep_copy

# create git repositroy
cd rep_copy
git init
git add -A
git commit -m "Initial commit."

# do some commited changes
echo "ABC" > README.rst
git add README.rst
git commit -m "Overwrite README."

git rm wrapper.py
git commit -m "Remove wrapper."

# extract the commits as patches
git format-patch `git rev-list HEAD | tail -n 1`
mv *.patch ..

# clone the fork
cd ..
git clone https://github.com/mhoff/pelican-global-rst-include rep_clone

# apply the patches as single commits
cd rep_clone
git am ../*.patch
```

*I am unsure whether `git am ../*.patch` will apply the commits in the right order. For me it worked that way.*

---

If you created one commit only you can also simply sync the files and recreate the commit manually. The following example uses `rsync`, however every program can be used which is able to reflect all modifications, additions and deletions (and e.g. file permission changes).

```
# create the copy
wget https://github.com/mhoff/pelican-global-rst-include/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip && rm master.zip && mv pelican-global-rst-include-master rep_copy

# create git repository
cd rep_copy
git init
git add -A
git commit -m "Initial commit."

# do some commited changes
echo "ABC" > README.rst
git add README.rst
git rm wrapper.py
git commit -m "Some changes."

# clone the fork
cd ..
git clone https://github.com/mhoff/pelican-global-rst-include rep_clone

# transfer changes, e.g. via rsync
rsync -avz --delete --cvs-exclude rep_copy/ rep_clone/

# recreate commit from copied changes
cd rep_clone
git add README.rst
git rm wrapper.py
git commit -m "Some changes"
```